# Derivation of optical resolution

Tags: optics, visible-light, wavelength

I'm trying to prove optical resolution formula from scratch and im having a hard time doing it. I dont know much about optics (im studying cosmology) and i need a detailed proof of optical resolution formula which is:

[image]

I dont know where did 1.22 constant came from. I red a topic about 1.22 being zero of bessel function but i dont know how all these connect to each other to create this formula.

Comment: [Airy disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk)

Comment: Perhaps start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_resolution#The_Rayleigh_criterion.

Comment: This question must have been asked before.

Comment: Thanks for the edit (im new here). and thank you  guys for guiding me.